# Calculate the ampere hour rating of a battery using current over time and voltage over time

Tags: voltage, batteries, ampere-hour, calculation

I built a battery and measured the current and voltage of the battery over time. Is there a way I can use this information easily to calculate the ampere hour capacity of the battery?

Comment: Yes there is...

Comment: Ah capacity is normalized for a 20h discharge. You can compute Ah or AVh=Wh in a spreadsheet

Comment: Asking for a link to another resource makes this a shopping question. VTC.

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate the current as a function of time, and express the result in ampere-hours. If the current is constant you can just multiply the current by the length of time, in hours, that the battery supplied this current.

Comment: Thank you, do you happen to know of an easy way to integrate the data using the data points?

Comment: Search the interwebs for "trapezoidal approximation".

Comment: Sorry for asking a lot of questions, but if I integrate current over time in seconds and divide the value by 3600, would I then get the amp-hour capacity of the battery?